# how to display html values from a database in a blade view in Laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a data in my database which contains HTML syntax. I want to display it in a blade view but it comes along with the html tags. How can i display the view?[image]

how do i display this in laravel without the tags but using the html format?

Comment: you should make sure this html content has been purified because you will need to output it without any escaping, so XSS issues could exist ... check the laravel docs for Blade for displaying data, there is a way to display unescaped data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unescape the element in blade.

Instead of:

```
{{ $element }}
```

Use:

```
{!! $element !!}
```

As Lagbox notes in the comments, it is important that if you use unescaped data, that you have purified it in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below:

```
{!!html_entity_decode($element)!!}
```